# How should I get to the actual node with a pointer to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, tree

I would like to set root_1's name to be "hi", just like the output of the current output of this code, which is mentioned below. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
struct Node 
{
    int num;
    char *name;
    struct Node *child;     
    struct Node *sibling;   
};

int main()
{

    struct Node root = {1,"hi",NULL,NULL};
    struct Node *root_0 = &root;
    struct Node **root_1 = &root_0;
    char *s = root.name; //s is now hi
    root_0 -> name = s;
    //*root_1 -> name = s;  //?????
    printf("%s\n", root_0 -> name);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how pointers work. `root_1` doesn't have a `name` or any other field - all it does is pointing to `root`. You don't have to set anything for `root_0` and `root_1`, you can access `root`'s name through them like this:

```
int main()
{

    struct Node root = { 1,"hi",NULL,NULL };
    struct Node *root_0 = &root;
    struct Node **root_1 = &root_0;

    printf("root_0: %s\n", root_0->name);
    printf("root_1: %s\n", (*root_1)->name);

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

> root_0: hi
>
> root_1: hi

So in other words, `(*root_1)->name` is `root_0->name`, which is `root.name`. Perhaps it's less confusing if you consider that `root_0->name` is the same as writing `(*root_0).name` and `(*root_1)->name` is like writing `(**root_1).name`. You just add a `*` per pointer level.

Comment: Ye, I was thinking the same thing (*root_1)->name should just act like root_0 ->name, but the thing is I would get an error says "error: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union" when I run my code above. But ur code runs perfectly fine, i don't get why lol.

Comment: wait a sec, is the parentheses around *root_1 is necessary in this case?

Comment: Yeah, it's necessary because of operator precedence. `->` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so the braces are necessary. Otherwise it would be evaluated as `*(root_1->name)`, which doesn't work because `root_1->name` means "the name of where `root_1` to", but it points to another pointer, and that doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 0):

It's just that * has a lower priority than ->.

*foo->bar = *(foo->bar) != (*foo)->bar.

So in your case you'd need (*root_1)->name = s;